# How to display a form's help_text when rendering django forms' fields manually?

Tags: python, html, django

So, in my Forms.py i have this:

```
class CustomerForm(forms.Form):
  name = forms.CharField(max_length=255,required=True,validators=[alphaonly],help_text="Enter your name")
```

And i'm trying to render it into a HTML like this:

```
<div class="form-row">
  {{ form.name.errors }}
  <div class="form-label">
    <label class="p-small" for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}">Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-input">
    {{ form.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is the help_text being displayed is the generic 'Please fill out this field' instead of the designated help_text i made. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

add field.help_text

```
<p>{{ form.name.help_text }}</p>
```

as follow:

```
<div class="form-row">
  {{ form.name.errors }}
  <div class="form-label">
    <label class="p-small" for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}">Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-input">
    {{ form.name }}
  </div>
  <p>{{ form.name.help_text }}</p>
</div>
```